# Why is my while loop not repeating?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

```
 var num = [1,1];
 var total = 0;
 var i = num.length;
 do {
    i++;
    num[i] = num[num.length-1] + num[num.length-2];
    total+=num[i];
    console.log(total);
 }
 while(num[num.length] < 4000000);
```

I've been working on the Project Euler questions for a day or two now to hopefully expand my knowledge and usefulness. On the second question I've been figuring out a (bad) way to get the fibonacci sequence. However my code will print "2" to console as it SHOULD but then stopping. Another issue I have is that just using the "while(X IS TRUE/FALSE) { DO STUFF }" just won't work. Not a clue why.

I'm probably just making dumb mistakes but somebody please enlighten me :)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do problem 2 of project euler. I know this isn't an answer, but something to consider is that you may not need to actually keep an array of all the fibonacci numbers. Arrays are complicating your process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `num` array has 2 elements, therefore `num.length` (and also `i`) are 2.  The 1st statement in your `do` block is `i++`.  Now `i` is 3.

You're setting `num[3]`, which means `num` is now `[1, 1, undefined, 1]`.

Also, in your `while`, you are checking `num[num.length]`.  Since arrays are zero-indexed, this will *never* work, as `num.length` is now 4.

What I suggest is: increment `i` after setting the element.  So, you push a new element, then increment the length counter.

```
var num = [1, 1],
    total = 0,
    i = 2;  // we already know the length, no need to get it
do {
    // we don't need the i++ here
    num[i] = num[i - 1] + num[i - 2]; // add the last 2 elements to the end
    total += num[i];
    console.log(total);
}
while (num[i++] < 4000000);  // "i++" increments i and returns its old value
```

Comment: A-hah! This did it. Thanks man, I can see what I needed to do now. Instead of fishing for the answer of num[3] I should ask for a number that actually exists within  the array so far.

Thanks for pointing out the while loop as well, didn't notice or think it through as I was typing it :P Little bit confused as to how the object in the array is utilized to get the next term though. 

Otherwise, nice response :)

Comment: @AlexMorris: In your array, there are `2` elements (indexes `0` and `1`), so `num[2]` will add a 3rd element to the array. :-)

Comment: I see :) With some modifications I got some more code done but sadly it's not right :(( I'll keep working on it though.

Answer (score 3):

`num.length` will always be 1 bigger than the last index of `num`, i.e. if `num.length` is 5, `num` has the indices 0 through 4, `num[5]` doesn't exist.

The highest available index will be `num.length - 1` so try `num[num.length - 1]` in your while's condition.

Comment: Well the Fibonacci sequence takes the last two terms and adds them together to make the next. I guess my problem is that my code isn't keeping an indices for the terms and just not advancing. Tried your suggestion and only got NaN as the second print.

Comment: You do have a logic problem in your code too. `num` starts off with length 2, so `i` gets that number in your initializations. Then you immediately increment `i` inside the do...while. `num` will be [1, 1, ?, 1+?] by the end of your first iteration of the while loop.